# How to write a loop in REPL mode?

Tags: frida

I would like to execute a loop in REPL mode but I am getting a SyntaxError: expecting '('

```
var methods = eval(ObjC.classes.UIViewController.$methods);
for item in methods { console.log(item) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to command line shells and not to Frida or any other REPL tool.

This is a Single command and multiple lines subject of a shell in terminals.

To solve it, all you need to do is to add "\" at the end of each line.

Example:

```
var methods = eval(ObjC.classes.UIViewController.$methods);\
for (item in methods) { console.log(item) }\
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for iterating and invoking class methods

```js
var UIDevice = ObjC.classes.UIDevice.currentDevice();
UIDevice.$ownMethods
  .filter(function(method) { 
    return method.indexOf(':') == -1 /* filter out methods with parameters */
       && method.indexOf('+') == -1 /* filter out public methods */
  })
  .forEach(function(method) { 
    console.log(method, ':', UIDevice[method]())
  })
```

Update:

```js
var UIViewControllerInstance = ObjC.chooseSync(ObjC.classes.UIViewController)[0];
console.log('Sanity check =', UIViewControllerInstance, JSON.stringify(UIViewControllerInstance.$ownMethods, null, 2));
UIViewControllerInstance.$ownMethods
  .filter(method => { return method.indexOf(':') == -1 && method.indexOf('+') == -1 })
  .forEach(method => { 
    console.log(method, ':', UIViewControllerInstance[method]())
  })
```

Instead of looking for UIViewController instances on the heap, you have direct access through UIApplication
take a look @ https://frida.re/docs/examples/ios/

Comment: try the update, please provide the ouput,